# in php - how to access the Folders which are out side the Web root Directory

Tags: php, filesystems

How can we access the Folders out side the Web root Directory?

We are using WAMPSERVER 2.0 (Apache 2.2.11,php 5.3.0 & My Sql 5.1.36).

Answer (score 3):

```
usr
| - www
     |- docs
        |- A
     |- webroot
        |- index.php
```

Just use "normal" file paths. E.g. to access `A` in the `docs` folder from `index.php`, you can use relative paths like `../docs/A` or absolute paths like `/usr/www/docs/A`.

The "webroot" directory only marks the entry point for **URLs**. This has no effect on PHP files. They are just normal files in a filesystem and can therefore access other files in the system via ordinary file paths.

Comment: we have a Folder test1 in C Drive & i wanted to access this folder from Web root Directory www where there is Directory test and the url i try out as http://172.20.236.123/test/test1 is this Possible? Many thanks for the Instant Reply..

Comment: @mohammedk1000: Then I guess you can access the folder via `C:\test1` from your PHP script. If you don't know how to access files or directories in general, [have a look at the available functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.fileprocess.file.php).

Comment: As i am a Newbie in this, Cud u please provide the Script & where to place the php Sript - Great thanks

Comment: @mohammedk1000: This is not possible this way. As I said, the web root marks the entry point for a URL. The purpose is that one **cannot** access every file in the system via an URL. You can only access the files from inside your PHP script. Or you have to move or link this file in your web root directory.

Comment: means we need to write a php Scripts & in which we need to mention the Folders to access with other out side WWW ? Many thanks for the Instant Reply

Comment: how can we Link the files in web root directory

Comment: Dear Felix Kling, instead of moving the file in Web root directory I wanted to Link the files/Directory in Web root Directory, How can We Link the files/Directories in web root directory ? Many thanks for the Reply

Comment: @mohammedk1000: It is at easy as creating a normal link to a file in Windows. Sorry, I don't use Windows, but I guess you have to right click on the file you want to link to and select `Create link...` or similar and move the link to the web root.

Comment: yeah, i have already tried using Create Short curt to the folder & placing this Shotcurt in WEB Folder but which is Not Working!

Comment: @mohammedk1000: Mmh ok, maybe it does not work on Windows. Works for me on Linux. Sorry.

Comment: thanks for the Response Felix Kling, i coud not understand one thing about ur Reply " You can only access the files from inside your PHP script " It means we need to Write a PHP Script ? pleae Help me out in this - Great Thanks

Comment: @mohammedk1000: Well, you tagged the question as PHP so I was assuming your are using PHP anyway.

Comment: Dear, yeah we are using PHP & fyi We are using WAMPSERVER 2.0(Apache 2.2.11,php 5.3.0 & My Sql 5.1.36 )

Comment: hi Experts, please Help me out in Resolving my Requirement. Great thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to learn how to read directories in php http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/working_with_directories.php